# Can I create another partition on a single partition system?

Tags: 13.10, partitioning, ext4

I have a system running Ubuntu 13.10 in a single partition. I need to create another ext4 partition, is it possible without reinstalling Ubuntu?

Please show me the procedure, if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create another ext4 partition from the single Ubuntu partition without reinstalling using Gparted Partition Editor.

For this you have to boot from Ubuntu live disk or Gparted live disk.Please note that you can't able to resize a mounted partition in Gparted.

Follow the steps given in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/18525/202806) answer.

Comment: Can you show me how?

Comment: Does that work if Ubuntu used whole HDD?

Comment: ya sure,it works.

Comment: Thanks, i will try that. Do i have to reinstall grub after that?

Comment: You don't need to reinstall grub after that.